# Why the z-scores values stays mostly between -3 and 3?

Tags: z-score, feature-engineering

I was reading through the [Google Machine learning](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/representation/cleaning-data) crash course and I can't digest the below point:

- Scaling with Z scores means that most scaled values will be between $-3$ and $+3,$ but a few values will be a little higher or lower than that range.

  > scaled_Value = (value - mean) / standard_deviation

For example:

For `1,2,3,4,5`,

> mean=3
>
> zscore calculated for each value would be -1.67, 0.83, 0 , 0.83, 1.67
>
> and the respective scaled values would be `-1.67, -1.67, 0, 3.332, 8.35`

Could anyone explain, What I am doing wrong and what's the correct way to understand z-score?

Comment: The z scores are already scaled. I don't understand why you're trying to scale them again.

Comment: What are these "respective scaled values"? How did you produce them?

Comment: Chebyshev's Inequality guarantees that no more than $1/9$ of all data can have an absolute z-score greater than 3.  It's unclear what your "scaled values" might be: your formula is that of a Z-score and your list of "scaled values" seem to have little to do with the z-scores you quote.

Answer (score 2):

A larger sample may lead to a clearer example. The theoretical model for 
z-scores is the standard normal distribution. Using R, I can generate
a sample of size $n = 200$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0,\, \sigma=1).$

```
set.seed(1031);  z = rnorm(200)
mean(z);  sd(z)
[1] -0.05595964   # aprx E(Z) = 0
[1] 1.014472      # aprx SD(Z) = 1
```

The sample mean $\bar Z = -0.056$ is nearly the same as the population mean
$\mu = 0$ and the sample standard deviation $S = 1.014$ is nearly the same
as the population standard deviation $\sigma = 1.$ (I could 'standardize'
by taking $\frac{Z_i - (-0.056)}{1.014},$ but that would not make much
difference in the values, and is not necessary for our demonstration.)

The R code below makes a histogram of the 200 observations. The tick marks
below the histogram (made by `rug`) show the exact locations of each of
the 200 observations. The red curve is the density curve of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0,\, \sigma=1).$ (The histogram matches the density curve roughly;
the match would be better with an even larger sample.)

```
hist(z, prob=T, col="skyblue2", xlim=c(-3.5,3.5),
   main="Histogram of sample of 200 from NORM(0,1)")
rug(z)
curve(dnorm(x), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

From the figure we can see that only one observed value falls outside the
interval $(-3,3).$ Specifically, the value -3.161 lies below -3 and no value lies
above 3.

```
z[z < -3]
[1] -3.160774
z[z > 3]
numeric(0)
```

Generally speaking, 99.7% of standard normal random variates
lie inside $(-3,3)$ and 0.3% lie outside this interval. So
that's an average of about 0.6 observations out of 200; it is
no surprise that we saw only one value outside $(-3,3).$ In a sample
of size $n=5$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ it would be rare to see
any observation outside $(-3,3).$

```
diff(pnorm(c(-3,3)))
[1] 0.9973002
```

*Note:* I'm not sure that your sample $x=(1,2,3,4,5)$
is a sample from a normal distribution, but standardizing with $\bar X$ and
$S_x$ I get values between $-1.265$ and $+1.265$ --- certainly nothing close to
$\pm 3.$ Normal or not, this sample is not really large enough to illustrate
the idea you're exploring.

```
x = 1:5; x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
(x - mean(x))/sd(x)
[1] -1.2649111 -0.6324555  0.0000000  0.6324555  1.2649111
```